# Is it possible to modify code generated by PhoneGap and how would this effect apps market application process?

Tags: ios4, cordova

Is it possible to modify/supplement code generated by PhoneGap to modify/add functionality? And how does this effect the application's likelihood of being accepted into the apps market?

The reason I am asking is because there are certain components of the desired iPhone application that we would like to have that we can not achieve with our converted CakePHP web application. These desired items include QR code scanning and augmented reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

You can look there for already written (and validated) plugins.

If I remember correctly, a qrscanner plugin already exists.

Augmented reality it not really possible with phonegap. (At least not as far as I know) As you can't manipulate the camera view with phonegap.

Maby if you would write a plugin for it. But that would mean writing almost the whole application in objective-C.

Comment: Hey Erik - thanks for the input. Could you shoot me a link to the qrscanner plugin as I have looked but have been unable to find it. My only question after reading your answer is: Is there a way to create custom plugins for the individual devices? Such as customize objective-c that will be used for the iPhone, etc etc for Android and Blackberry?

Comment: Yes, making your own extensions is possible within phonegap. The QRscanner doesn't work on every platform. There is zebraxing for android, and zbar works on the iPhone. These should be used as a phonegap plugin though. A decoding webservice is possible too using a cli application like QRcode. And using php exec();